# Theory to Signature Mapping?

Tags: first-order-logic, predicate-logic, higher-order-logic, second-order-logic

So let’s say that I have a theory **T** with a signature Σ. I want to make another signature Σ’. The logic behind Σ is one/non-sorted, while the logic Σ’ I want to be many-sorted. Is there any means of “mapping” or partitioning **T** into Σ’? What would this be called?

Comment: What is the relation between $\Sigma$ and $\Sigma'$? Or is $\Sigma'$ completely arbitrary (in which case why would you expect a way to translate into it)?

Comment: I think you mean "language" rather than "logic". It is very unclear what you are asking. First of all you need to decide what the sorts you want to have in your many-sorted theory. It might help if you can give a specific example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: @RobArthan yes, “language” is precisely what I meant. **T** is from a high-order language and I’m wanting to partition up various terms from **T** such that they gain a new “meaning”, in Σ’ through this abstraction. I’m not quite sure what levels of precision are needed so be patient lol